# How long does beef stays good after turning of refrigerator?

Tags: meat, freezing, beef

During this weekend I accidentally turned of my refrigerator connection before going out and It was like this for about 50 hours without the connection. I had raw beef in there in almost an airtight packet ,when I opened it today , it was still cold , but not frozen. Is it safe to eat this meat ?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can tell you that the beef is still safe, there are just too many variables. However, if you didn't open the refrigerator during the time it was off, and it looks and smells fine; I'd still eat it. However, I wouldn't serve it to anybody else without full disclosure. Obviously, the standard caveat of not serving it to pregnant women or anyone immunocompromised applies.

The safest route is always **When in Doubt Throw it Out!**